# How do I loop through the following json list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, list, for-loop

I am coding a `jQuery` `ajax` function that retrieves a list and I need to iterate through this `list`.

This is the code I am using to serialize the list:

```
JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(listData);
```

Here is the json data after the data has been retrieved:

```
jsonData = "[{\"draggable\":false,\"icon\":null,\"latitude\":-41.22766,\"longitude\":174.812761,\"title\":\"LocationMarker1 74 Title\"},{\"draggable\":false,\"icon\":null,\"latitude\":-41.228029,\"longitude\":174.812926,\"title\":\"LocationMarker2 80 Title\"}]"
```

How do I iterate through this json list so that I can retrieve the individual values?

I have tried the following:

```
success: function (mapMarkerData) {
    for (var MapMarker in mapMarkerData) {
        alert(MapMarker["latitude"]);
        alert(MapMarker["longitude"]);
        alert(MapMarker["title"]);
        alert(MapMarker["draggable"]);
    }
}
```

For each alert, I am getting the following message:

> undefined

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you parse the string into an object?

Comment: You need to parse the string into object and also it's an array. So you need to do a for loop and then alert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
success: function (mapMarkerData) {
    for (i in mapMarkerData) {
        alert(mapMarkerData[i].latitude);
        alert(mapMarkerData[i].longitude);
        alert(mapMarkerData[i].title);
        alert(mapMarkerData[i].draggable);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Works exactly as I need.

Answer (score 1):

```
var jsonData = "[{\"draggable\":false,\"icon\":null,\"latitude\":-41.22766,\"longitude\":174.812761,\"title\":\"LocationMarker1 74 Title\"},{\"draggable\":false,\"icon\":null,\"latitude\":-41.228029,\"longitude\":174.812926,\"title\":\"LocationMarker2 80 Title\"}]"


jsonData = JSON.parse(jsonData) //Parse it to make object

jsonData.forEach(function(val){
    alert(val.draggable);
    .
    .
    .
    alert(val.title);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution.

```js
var jsonData = "[{\"draggable\":false,\"icon\":null,\"latitude\":-41.22766,\"longitude\":174.812761,\"title\":\"LocationMarker1 74 Title\"},{\"draggable\":false,\"icon\":null,\"latitude\":-41.228029,\"longitude\":174.812926,\"title\":\"LocationMarker2 80 Title\"}]";

var obj = JSON.parse(jsonData);

$.each(obj, function(i, row){
  alert(row.draggable);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json2/20140204/json2.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = $.parseJSON(jsonData);
for(var o in x){
   console.log(x[o].latitude);
   console.log(x[o].longitude);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution would be like

```
var data = Json.Parse(jsonData); for (int i=0; i< data.length; i++){ alert(data[i]["latitude"]); }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code:

```
var jsonData = "[{\"draggable\":false,\"icon\":null,\"latitude\":-41.22766,\"longitude\":174.812761,\"title\":\"LocationMarker1 74 Title\"},{\"draggable\":false,\"icon\":null,\"latitude\":-41.228029,\"longitude\":174.812926,\"title\":\"LocationMarker2 80 Title\"}]";

var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonData);
for(var index in jsonObj)
   alert(jsonObj[index].title);
```